# Можно ли получить список timezone -ов из класса Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel

Как видно конструктор класса Carbon принимает параметр timezone

```
$carbon = new Carbon('first day of January 2008', 'America/Vancouver');
```

но есть ли возможность  получить из класса Carbon или PHP список всех временных зон ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755704/php-timezone-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией PHP - [DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)

```
$timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
foreach ($timezone_identifiers as $timezone) {
    echo "$timezone<br/>";
}
```

Результат:

```
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
Africa/Algiers
Africa/Asmara
Africa/Bamako
Africa/Bangui
Africa/Banjul
Africa/Bissau
Africa/Blantyre
Africa/Brazzaville
Africa/Bujumbura
Africa/Cairo
Africa/Casablanca
Africa/Ceuta
Africa/Conakry
Africa/Dakar
Africa/Dar_es_Salaam
...
Pacific/Pago_Pago
Pacific/Palau
Pacific/Pitcairn
Pacific/Pohnpei
Pacific/Port_Moresby
Pacific/Rarotonga
Pacific/Saipan
Pacific/Tahiti
Pacific/Tarawa
Pacific/Tongatapu
Pacific/Wake
Pacific/Wallis
UTC
```